# Getting "A JavaScript error was encountered clearing the element. The driver assumes this is because the element is hidden" error

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I got this error first time, for this my selenium script was able to identify the Username web element but got this exception while entering data in text box.

For UserName element I added explicit wait like below-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 120, 1000);
logger.info("Finding by ID");
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(strConst)));
logger.info(strConst + " element display -" + element.isDisplayed());
cnf.webEditTxtChange(sUtils.getElementById(loginElms.userName),userName,loginTest,"Username");
```

I can see both the logger info displayed in log and then below error

Error:

```
A JavaScript error was encountered clearing the element. The driver assumes this is because the element is hidden, disabled or read-only, and it must not be to clear the element.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'bld02600012', ip: '10.54.228.104', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:64418/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, webdriver.remote.sessionid: aefaa1f1-83db-418f-a3f0-1c5...}
Session ID: aefaa1f1-83db-418f-a3f0-1c5505b1e964
2020-09-12 18:32:14,248  INFO [TestNG-tests-2] [AppUtils:50] - Login : A JavaScript error was encountered clearing the element. The driver assumes this is because the element is hidden, disabled or read-only, and it must not be to clear the element.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'bld02600012', ip: '10.54.228.104', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:64418/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, webdriver.remote.sessionid: aefaa1f1-83db-418f-a3f0-1c5...}
Session ID: aefaa1f1-83db-418f-a3f0-1c5505b1e964
```

1. selenium - 3.141.59
2. testng - 6.14.3
3. maven - 3.6.0
4. IEDriver - 3.14.0

Can someone help to understand what this error cause?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
A JavaScript error was encountered clearing the element. The driver assumes this is because the element is hidden, disabled or read-only, and it must not be to clear the element.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'bld02600012', ip: '10.54.228.104', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
```

...implies that the **IEDriverServer** was unable to interact with the new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **InternetExplorer Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *java.version* is **1.8.0_112** which is quite **old** and **ancient**.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u252](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).